# Cannot compile Delphes on MacOS 13.2 x86_64, emitting multiples errors such as missing namespace and templates

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, macos-ventura

I want to recompile the Delphes program for an additional lib file, when I get the error when running `make`:

```
>> Generating tmp/classes/ClassesDict.cc
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:93:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:135:9: error: no member named 'at_quick_exit' in the global namespace
using ::at_quick_exit _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdlib:136:9: error: no member named 'quick_exit' in the global namespace
using ::quick_exit _LIBCPP_USING_IF_EXISTS;
      ~~^
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:85:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:485:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_pod.h:29:38: error: no template named 'is_trivially_default_constructible'; did you mean
      'is_nothrow_default_constructible'?
    : public integral_constant<bool, is_trivially_default_constructible<...
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_nothrow_default_constructible.h:22:50: note: 'is_nothrow_default_constructible' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_nothrow_default_cons...
                                                 ^
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:85:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:485:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_pod.h:30:38: error: no template named 'is_trivially_copy_constructible'; did you mean
      'is_nothrow_copy_constructible'?
                                     is_trivially_copy_constructible<_Tp...
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_nothrow_copy_constructible.h:24:50: note: 'is_nothrow_copy_constructible' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_nothrow_copy_constructible
                                                 ^
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:85:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:485:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_pod.h:31:38: error: no template named 'is_trivially_copy_assignable'; did you mean
      'is_nothrow_copy_assignable'?
                                     is_trivially_copy_assignable<_Tp>::...
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_nothrow_copy_assignable.h:24:50: note: 'is_nothrow_copy_assignable' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_nothrow_copy_assignable
                                                 ^
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:85:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:485:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_pod.h:32:38: error: no template named 'is_trivially_destructible'
                                     is_trivially_destructible<_Tp>::value> {};
                                     ^
In file included from input_line_1:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:85:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:496:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_trivial.h:25:31: error: no template named 'is_trivially_copyable'
    : integral_constant<bool, is_trivially_copyable<_Tp>::value &&
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_trivial.h:26:34: error: no template named 'is_trivially_default_constructible'; did you mean
      'is_nothrow_default_constructible'?
                                 is_trivially_default_constructible<_Tp>::value>
                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_nothrow_default_constructible.h:22:50: note: 'is_nothrow_default_constructible' declared here
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_nothrow_default_cons...
                                                 ^
In file included from input_line_3:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:36:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__assert:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__availability:289:5: error: "It looks like you're trying to enable vendor availability markup, but you
      haven't defined the corresponding macros yet!"
#   error "It looks like you're trying to enable vendor availability mar...
    ^
In file included from input_line_3:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:36:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__assert:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:42:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:44:17: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_NORETURN _LIBCPP_OVERRIDABLE_FUNC_VIS _LIBCPP_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT(_...
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:47:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
^
In file included from input_line_3:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:38:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:18:28: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:21:50: error: no variable template matches partial specialization
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS enable_if<true, _Tp> {t...
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:21:72: error: expected expression
  ...<class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS enable_if<true, _Tp> {typedef _T...
                                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:39: error: cannot template a using declaration
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBU...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:59: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBU...
                                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:96: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Bp'
  ...void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = typename enable_if<_Bp, _Tp>...
                                                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:29:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
^
In file included from input_line_3:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:39:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:18:28: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:35:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:35:28: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:35:58: error: no member named 'value' in the global namespace
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
                                                       ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:37:9: error: no template named 'integral_constant'
typedef integral_constant<bool, true>  true_type;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:38:9: error: no template named 'integral_constant'
typedef integral_constant<bool, false> false_type;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:41:1: error: cannot template a using declaration
using _BoolConstant _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = integral_constant<bool, _Val>;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:41:21: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
using _BoolConstant _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = integral_constant<bool, _Val>;
                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
In file included from input_line_4:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/etc/root/cling/lib/clang/9.0.1/include/assert.h:8:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:42:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:81:2: warning: "Unsupported compiler detected" [-W#warnings]
#warning "Unsupported compiler detected"
 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:913:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from input_line_4:2:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/Rtypes.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:36:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__assert:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__availability:289:5: error: "It looks like you're trying to enable vendor availability markup, but you
      haven't defined the corresponding macros yet!"
#   error "It looks like you're trying to enable vendor availability mar...
    ^
In file included from input_line_4:2:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/Rtypes.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:36:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__assert:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:42:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:44:17: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_NORETURN _LIBCPP_OVERRIDABLE_FUNC_VIS _LIBCPP_ATTRIBUTE_FORMAT(_...
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__verbose_abort:47:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
^
In file included from input_line_4:2:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/Rtypes.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:38:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:18:28: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:21:50: error: no variable template matches partial specialization
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS enable_if<true, _Tp> {t...
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:21:72: error: expected expression
  ...<class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS enable_if<true, _Tp> {typedef _T...
                                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:39: error: cannot template a using declaration
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBU...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:59: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
template <bool _Bp, class _Tp = void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBU...
                                                          ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:23:96: error: use of undeclared identifier '_Bp'
  ...void> using __enable_if_t _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = typename enable_if<_Bp, _Tp>...
                                                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/enable_if.h:29:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD'
_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
^
In file included from input_line_4:2:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/Rtypes.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root/6.26.06_2/include/root/RtypesCore.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:39:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:18:28: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:35:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:35:28: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR const _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:37:9: error: no template named 'integral_constant'
typedef integral_constant<bool, true>  true_type;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:38:9: error: no template named 'integral_constant'
typedef integral_constant<bool, false> false_type;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:41:1: error: cannot template a using declaration
using _BoolConstant _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = integral_constant<bool, _Val>;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX13.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/integral_constant.h:41:21: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
using _BoolConstant _LIBCPP_NODEBUG = integral_constant<bool, _Val>;
                    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
Error: Error loading the default rootcling header files.
make: *** [tmp/classes/ClassesDict.cc] Error 1
```

I find it peculiar that I'm experiencing these issues, as I haven't updated my OS recently and the last time I installed Delphes, the compilation ran smoothly, so I'm not sure why the situation has changed. The official Delphes installation instructions can be found [here](https://cp3.irmp.ucl.ac.be/projects/delphes/wiki/WorkBook/QuickTour), which I do follow both this time and last time.

These errors I'm encountering are diverse, making it difficult for me to identify a common thread or solution.

Additional question: I suspect these problems might be related to updates in Xcode.app or Xcode CTL, considering Apple's history of quietly discontinuing support for older versions of its tools. Is there a way to isolate these environments or circumvent these issues other than using a virtual machine?

I would appreciate any guidance on the cause of these issues or suggestions on how to resolve them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you are compiling to a modern C++ standard, C++17 should be sufficient. Macs are known to default to C++98.

Comment: @user4581301 Apologies, but I continue to encounter the issue after executing `make CXXFLAGS='-std=c++17`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries. It's always good to clear out the low-hanging fruit early. I'd add that comment to the question where it's more permanent and more easily found.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out the solution. Post my suggestion in case anyone runs into this issue.

The ROOT distribution I used first was from `brew`. It worked fine in most cases because the dependencies request is not that strict, but after sometime (e.g. the system was upgraded) some dependencies started to mismatch.

**My solution is to just install ROOT using `conda`** and let all the depencency come along with the environment, and it worked. And if this does not work for you, try other distributions, e.g. compiling ROOT from the source.

This sounds ridiculous because different distributions should be identical and should solve the depenencies for themselves, but I guess this isn't the case and the depenencies are not resolved that well, because if you install ROOT using conda environment on MacOS X, you may encounter some `ld` errors complaining an incorrect version. The reason is that when you activate an environment, the dependencise come with the environment becomes the first in your `$PATH`, same for the `ld` on which the conda itself depends, and this becomes a question when ROOT needs `ld` with the system version instead of the conda version. The solution to this is just replace the `ld` from conda with the `/usr/bin/ld` using a soft link.

There should be some mistakes in this explaination, if you see any please correct me.